# Disable touchpad while typing and also touchpad click for X session

Tags: x11, touchpad

I have done a lot of googling for disable touchpad click and disable touchpad while typing and found a lot of answers. However most of them are related to a desktop enviornment. I do not use a DE.

So, I need to:

- Completely disable touchpad clicks always

*and*

- Disable touchpad while typing (like scrolling, moving mouse)

Answer (score 1):

> Disable touchpad while typing (like scrolling, moving mouse)

I was able to achieve this by adding `syndaemon -i 1 -d &` to my ~/.xinitrc file.

The number 1 here is seconds, which is how long to to wait to activate the touchpad after the last key is pressed.

> Completely disable touchpad clicks always

I was partially able to achieve this by adding 

`Section "InputClass"
       Identifier "touchpad catchall"
       Driver "synaptics"
       MatchIsTouchpad "on"
       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
       Option "MaxTapTime"             "0"
EndSection`

 to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf

I say partially here because it does prevent click on unwanted windows, but it does not prevent accidental activation on background windows by scrolling on them

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Synaptics touchpad, its properties can be changed for running X server with synclient program, more info [here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/synclient.1.html) and [here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html). For example, to disable tap ("click") action, use

```
synclient TapButton1=0
```

To list available configuration options:

```
synclient -l
```

You might be particularly interested in

> ```
> Option "TouchpadOff" "integer"
>  Switch off the touchpad. Valid values are:
>  0 Touchpad is enabled
>  1 Touchpad is switched off
>  2 Only tapping and scrolling is switched off
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I use `xinput`

## how to use xinput

`xinput` lists all the input devices currently recognized by your X-server. Find the one you are interested in and remember the id.

Next, list the properties of that device with `xinput list-porps $input_id`.

This looks scary, but really it is just a list of settings, that you can change.

Have a look at the properties and see if you find sth, that is interesting to you, remember the id of the property. With `xinput set-prop $input_id $prop_id $new_value` you can change the setting.

## an example:

```bash
$ xinput
...
⎜   ↳ Touchpad                  id=12

...
```

My touchpad has the id 12. Let's check its properties:

```bash
$ xinput list-props 12
...
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (331):    1
...
```

The setting to disable the touchpad while typing has the id 331 and is enabled (value of 1), we now want to disable this setting

```bash
$ xinput set-prop 12 331 0
```

Now the touchpad should remain usable while typing.

## important note

property changes you make with xinput are not permanent and are lost with the X-server, so if you want to have them everytime you must include them in your startup script. Sounds simple enough, however: The ids can change depending on what peripherals you have connected on startup, meaning if you sometimes have a mouse connected when you start and sometimes you don't the ids can be different, so you need to identify them every time.

This is how I do it:

```
ID=$(xinput list|grep touch -i|sed -nr 's/.*id=([0-9]*).*/\1/p')
IN_TAP=$(xinput list-props $ID|grep "Disable While"|grep -v "Default" |sed -nr 's/.*\(([0-9][0-9][0-9])\).*/\1/p')
xinput set-prop $ID $IN_TAP 1
```